# How do I sum a row that I keep adding new data to on the left side?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a formula that totals the number of tardies for a student in column b when I insert a new column each day between column b and c (see example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1axI2nI7IgCDViEi_ZHKlz_h1N8kGBb4j-gXtp9bRyGQ/edit?usp=sharing))

when I use =sum(C2:2) it works until I add the column but then the formula changes to =sum(D2:2) and the new data is not counted.

I tried to use =sum(indirect("C2"):D2:2) but when I do that and drag the formula down the column it adds the row and adds it to the total of all the cells above (in this case B4 would be 6+3 = 9 and the student after if there was one would by 9 plus how every many tardies the following student has.

I'm sure this is an easy thing to do but I am stumped. Any help would be much appreciated.

I tried to use =sum(indirect("C2"):D2:2) but when I do that and drag the formula down the column it adds the row and adds it to the total of all the cells above (in this case B4 would be 6+3 = 9 and the student after if there was one would by 9 plus how every many tardies the following student has.

I'm sure this is an easy thing to do but I am stumped. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this arrayformula:

```
=BYROW(INDIRECT("C3:Z"),lambda(rowx,if(counta(rowx)=0,,sum(rowx))))
```

[image]

Comment: What witchcraft is this?! Will it work if my rows continue out past Z? Also, thank you very much; I really appreciate it. Is there any chance you are willing to explain this to me? If you are too busy, no worries and I completely understand.

Comment: i mean i've arbitrarily set the column max to Z but you can change it as needed. and you can look into the byrow function here (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en). its explained with clear examples here and should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C2:2"))
```

---

```
=BYROW(INDIRECT("C2:1000"); LAMBDA(x; SUM(x)))
```

Comment: This is what I tried, but then I can't drag it down and have it work for some resason. On my real sheet I am doing this for over 1000 students. The formula that rockinfreakshow gave me worked, but I can't even begin to understand it.

Comment: @BarrySmith you can do: `=BYROW(INDIRECT("C2:1000"); LAMBDA(x; SUM(x)))` (no need of dragging)